# Angular Cli Installation failuer - angular-cli/chokidents

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular-cli

Latest Node version 6.7.0

I got this error while installation saying `notsup` not compatible with operating system

Windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please first clear cache of npm(npm cache clean). So, you will receive the latest version of npm package.

If you still facing same issue, then you need to append npm permission. For that you can follow below link.

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Answer (score 0):

What's shown in the screenshot are all warnings and should not prevent the install.

However, check [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39884520/freshly-installed-angular-cli-gives-error-rather-than-running/39893951#39893951) for all things you can try if this is failing.

Basically, try running the following:

```
npm rm -g angular-cli
npm cache clear
npm i -g angular-cli --no-optional
```

Let me know how it goes.