# Freshly installed Angular Cli gives error rather than running

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have been trying to install the latest angular-cli in order to start a new project, but I've been encountering a very strange issue. When I run

```
npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

angular-cli will seem to install successfully.  However, when I actually try to use it or check the version with

```
ng --version
```

I get this error:

```
fs.js:640
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
             ^

TypeError: path must be a string or Buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at Function.Version.fromProject (/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:87:31)
    at Function.Version.isPreWebpack (/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:111:31)
    at Function.Version.assertPostWebpackVersion (/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/upgrade/version.js:97:18)
    at /Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng:25:15
    at /Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
    at ondir (/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:187:31)
    at /Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:153:39
```

I have found lots of answers for similar errors, but they all seem to suggest that the issue was resolved in v1.0.0-beta.15, while I should have installed v1.0.0-beta.16.  Regardless, when I follow the most popular suggestion I can find of commenting out line 25 of ng (Version.assertPostWebpackVersion();), I just get a different error:

```
→ ng --version
module.js:457
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../models/config'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ryan/node_modules/angular-cli/packages/angular-cli/addon/index.js:4:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Function.Addon.lookup (/Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addon.js:879:19)
    at /Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addons-factory.js:47:36
    at visit (/Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/DAG.js:23:3)
    at DAG.topsort (/Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/DAG.js:82:7)
    at AddonsFactory.initializeAddons (/Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/addons-factory.js:44:9)
    at Project.initializeAddons (/Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:374:36)
    at Function.Project.nullProject (/Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:131:16)
    at Function.Project.projectOrnullProject (/Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:640:22)
    at module.exports (/Users/ryan/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/cli/index.js:94:25)
    at module.exports (/Users/ryan/node_modules/angular-cli/packages/angular-cli/lib/cli/index.js:45:10)
    at /Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng:36:5
    at /Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:44:21
    at ondir (/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:187:31)
    at /Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:153:39
    at onex (/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:93:22)
    at /Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:24:18
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

node: v6.7.0

npm: 3.10.3

os: osx El Capitan

EDIT: Additional information about my current setup, as requested by comments in answer submissions:

```
→ npm list -g typescript
/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib
└─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16
  ├─┬ @angular-cli/ast-tools@1.0.2
  │ └── typescript@2.0.0
  ├─┬ typedoc@0.4.5
  │ └── typescript@1.8.10
  └── typescript@2.0.2

→ npm list -g webpack
/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib
└─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16
  └── webpack@2.1.0-beta.22

→ npm list -g angular-cli
/Users/ryan/.nvm/versions/node/v6.7.0/lib
└── angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try running `ng --version` in a directory with no *node_modules* and *package.json*, which can affect the result.

Try do the following to update all your global packages:

```
npm update -g
```

My OS X setup

```
> ng --version                                                                                                     
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.16                                                                                                                               
node: 6.7.0                                                                                                                                              
os: darwin x64                                                                                                                                           
> node -v                                                                                                          
v6.7.0                                                                                                                                                   
> npm -v                                                                                                           
3.10.8                                                                                                                                                   
> npm list -g typescript                                                                                           
/usr/local/lib                                                                                                                                           
├─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16                                                                                                                            
│ ├─┬ @angular-cli/ast-tools@1.0.2                                                                                                                       
│ │ └── typescript@2.0.0                                                                                                                                 
│ ├─┬ typedoc@0.4.5                                                                                                                                      
│ │ └── typescript@1.8.10                                                                                                                                
│ └── typescript@2.0.2                                                                                                                                   
└─┬ typings@1.4.0                                                                                                                                        
  └─┬ typings-core@1.5.0                                                                                                                                 
    └── typescript@2.0.3                                                                                                                                 

> npm list -g webpack                                                                                              
/usr/local/lib                                                                                                                                           
├─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16                                                                                                                            
│ └── webpack@2.1.0-beta.22                                                                                                                              
└── webpack@1.13.2                                                                                                                                       

> npm list -g angular-cli                                                                                          
/usr/local/lib                                                                                                                                           
└── angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.16
```

Comment: Just tried that as per your suggestion, but it hasn't changed the error I'm getting unfortunately.

Comment: @RyanAnderson that is strange, I get the same setup as yours on OS X. Do you get similar output as my `npm list` in the answer? Also, try `ng --version` outside of any project directory.

Comment: I have very almost identical results to your `npm list` command, although I'm using nvm for my node, and I don't have typings and the older version of webpack.  As for running `ng --version` outside of a project directory, none of my commands that I have posted the output of were run inside of a project directory.

Comment: @RyanAnderson If you are not running inside a project dir, then it will not be affected by node_modules and package.json, which can be the case. Unless you are running in your home dir and there is a node_modules dir there.

Comment: ...Huh.  I have a node_modules dir in my home dir.  I have no idea how I managed that.  I deleted it and it solved my problem immediately.  Thank you, @JohnSiu!

Comment: @RyanAnderson Updated answer with your findings :D

Answer (score 0):

### Prerequisites

First, ensure you have Node 4.x and NPM 3.x.

Note that Node 4.x (at least up to 4.4.2, possibly newer versions) comes with NPM 2.x not 3.x.

So, if you have Node 4.x, upgrade NPM to latest by running:

```
npm i -g npm
```

(Use `sudo` if needed; and BTW, run install as shown, not update)

If you have Node 0.10 or 0.12, you probably want to install it, and look in your `~/` directory for any files or folders mentioning node or npm and remove them. Those versions were so sticky.

### Clean Install

Now, assuming you have all the right versions, run:

```
npm rm -g angular-cli
npm cache clear
npm i -g angular-cli
```

### More Troubleshooting

If this doesn't work, repeat the previous 3 lines, but add `--no-optional` to the install line, so this becomes:

```
npm rm -g angular-cli
npm cache clear
npm i -g angular-cli --no-optional
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I'm currently running node v6.7.0 and npm 3.10.3, so I don't think that they are to blame.  I tried running a clean install as you suggested, both with and without `--no-optional`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Hello @RyanAnderson, I came across a similar issue. Please refer to my solution at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907921/invalid-angular-cli-ast-tools-error-while-installing-angular-cli-on-mac-os-x-e    You might need to update your npm to 3.10.9 and then try installing angular-cli again. Thanks