# Invalid @angular-cli/ast-tools error while installing angular-cli on Mac OS X (El Capitan)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I get the following error when I run `sudo npm install -g @angular-cli@latest` on Mac OS X (El Capitan)

```
Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli@latest"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm v3.10.3

npm ERR! Invalid name: "@angular-cli/ast-tools"
```

Following are the debug logs:

```
2911 verbose stack Error: Invalid name: "@angular-cli/ast-tools"
2911 verbose stack at ensureValidName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:281:15)
2911 verbose stack at Object.fixNameField (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:196:5)
2911 verbose stack at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:29:38
2911 verbose stack at Array.forEach (native)
2911 verbose stack at normalize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:28:15)
2911 verbose stack at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:349:5)
2911 verbose stack at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:124:5)
2911 verbose stack at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:214:31
2911 verbose stack at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:17:25)
2911 verbose stack at Glob. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/glob/glob.js:146:7)
2912 verbose cwd /Users/XXX
2913 error Darwin 15.4.0
2914 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "angular-cli@latest"
2915 error node v6.7.0
2916 error npm v3.10.3
2917 error Invalid name: "@angular-cli/ast-tools"
```

It looks like this is an existing issue in the angular-cli installation https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2187

Could someone please suggest why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, an update to npm fixed this issue on Mac OS X (El Capitan).

Here's how I resolved this issue:

```
  sudo npm update npm -g
  npm --v
  node -v
  npm uninstall -g angular-cli
  sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
  sudo npm cache clean
  sudo npm install -g angular-cli@latest
```

After running the following commands, following were the versions of npm and node:

npm: 3.10.9

node: v6.6.0